# How to save array of objects in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I have this array 
[image]

I want set all keys and values in localstorage like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you can loop through the array, calling `localStorage.setItem()` setting the `key` and `val` properties for every property in your array of objects. Something like this:

```
yourArray.forEach(o => localStorage.setItem(o.key, o.val));
```